# Handle DateTime overflow in JULIA

Tags: datetime, julia

I know that Javascript Date() function can handle date entry overflows. But in Julia I get Error.
Is there any way to handle overflows automatically?

```
DateTime(2020, 4, 22, 15, 43, 67)  # ----> 2020-4-22T15:44:07
DateTime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 59, 60) # ----> 2021-1-1T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the default behavior of throwing an error useful. If you want to allow overflows you can define your own function for this eg. like this:

```
julia> MyDateTime(y, m, d, h, mi, s) = 
           +(DateTime(0), Year(y), Month(m-1), Day(d-1),
             Hour(h), Minute(mi), Second(s))
MyDateTime (generic function with 1 method)

julia> MyDateTime(2020, 4, 22, 15, 43, 67)  # ----> 2020-4-22T15:44:07
2020-04-22T15:44:07

julia> MyDateTime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 59, 60) # ----> 2021-1-1T00:00:00
2021-01-01T00:00:00
```

Note that the order of operations matters there - we first advance year, then month, etc. (as e.g. the effect of advancing time by one second may depend on the month, year and day):

```
julia> MyDateTime(2020, 2, 28, 23, 59, 60)
2020-02-29T00:00:00

julia> MyDateTime(2021, 2, 28, 23, 59, 60)
2021-03-01T00:00:00
```

(this can get especially tricky if you have very large and invalid values of month, day etc.)